# HAProxy - SSL SNI inconvenience

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I found some inconvenience in haproxy 1.5 when i try to configure SSL SNI.

There is a fragment of haproxy configuration: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw/ndNZ8Va6)

I would like to pass client IP to backend. No matter how I configure reqadd / set-header X-Forwarded-For / Real-IP I always got a haproxy IP address in X-Forwarded-For.

Someone try to pass real IP with SSL SNI on HAProxy
? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this configuration, you seem to be doing SNI-sniffing, yet all of the backends are looping back to HAProxy itself... which is not a case where SNI-sniffing is required.  Perhaps I'm overlooking something else that would require this.

It should be apparent why you are getting the proxy's IP in `X-Forwarded-For` -- HAProxy is talking to itself. The first pass through the proxy *is* the client connection, as far as the proxy can determine on the second pass, because only the second pass is speaking HTTP.  It only sees that an incoming TCP connection has arrived... from itself.

The solution is for the first-pass backend to pass the original client information using the Proxy Protocol and the second-pass frontend to decode it.

Add `accept-proxy` to the `bind` lines for the second-pass frontends, and add `send-proxy` to the `server` lines on the first-pass backends.  This way, on the connection where HAProxy is talking to itself, the first-pass backend will send the Proxy protocol preamble and the second-pass frontend will decode the incoming value and place it in `X-Forwarded-For`.